# CLI php errors on FreeBSD Server

Tags: php, freebsd, php.ini

I manage a FreeBSD server running usual AMP setup. Apache, Mysql, Php-fmp

Everything is working fine. In order to help out with speeding up a couple of Wordpress sites; we run php cli to run the wp_crontab.php regularly. This is running without issue; however, I am regularly getting emails with the following:

```
PHP Warning:  Missing arginfo for Imagick::__tostring() in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Missing arginfo for Imagick::getimagehistogram() in Unknown on line 0
```

Php8.0

Would like to fix; but if not, what is the best practice for disabling these emails?

I have tried using

```
error_reporting=0
error_reporting=E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_Warning
```

And some other settings in hopes to suppress these warning until I figured out what library I need to fix.

So, 2 questions:

1. how to disable warnings from php on the CLI?
2. What are these 2 missing arginfo warnings and how could I possibly fix that?

Comment: To clarify. I am trying those settings in /usr/local/etc/php.ini

Answer (score 0):

Being unable to find and answer and finding a few articles of bugs specific to the 8.0 implementation when; I just returned to 7.4.16.

Cheers,
T